# Bootstrap v5 carousel captions being not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap carousel captions are not being responsive for 576px even after I used media queries or put them in a responsive bootstrap container. The carousel seems to not be responsive on the Bootstrap website as well.

Thanks

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/

Comment: We need some code or example please. Maybe this link can helps you : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: Please read document carefully https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-captions In Smaller viewports they hide captions intentionally

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, they Intentionally hide the caption in smaller screens using two classes `d-none d-md-block`. These classes makes caption Hidden on small devices. So I replaced them with `d-block` which makes caption visible in all sized screens.

Try this Code. It is an edited version from [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-captions)

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

You can see hiding elements docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)